# making a circle around a two dimensional array

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with making a turn inside a two dimensional array to output the elements in spiral. I tried this code, but it is outputting not enough elements, I tried to make some if statements outside of the loop to cover all cases for which the general algorithm doesn't output. Can you help suggesting some way to manage the correct output.

CODE

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <algorithm>
//#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int r, c;
    cin >> r >> c;
    int r_beg = 0, r_end = r - 1, c_beg = 0, c_end = c - 1;

    int **m = new int*[r];

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new int[c];
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int runs = min(r, c) / 2; runs--;) {

        for (int i = c_beg; i < c_end; i++)
            cout << m[r_beg][i] << " ";

        for (int i = r_beg; i < r_end; i++)
            cout << m[i][c_end] << " ";

        for (int i = c_end; i > c_beg; i--)
            cout << m[r_end][i] << " ";

        for (int i = r_end; i > r_beg; i--)
            cout << m[i][c_beg] << " ";

        r_beg++;
        c_beg++;
        r_end--;
        c_end--;
    }


    if (r <= c && c_beg <= c_end) {
        for (int i = c_beg; i <= c_end; i++)
            cout << m[r_end][i] << " ";
    }
    else if (r >= c && r_beg <= r_end) {
        for (int i = r_beg; i <= r_end; i++)
            cout << m[i][c_end] << " ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        delete[] m[i];
    delete[] m;

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

Input:

```
3 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output: `1 2 3 6 9 8 7 4 5`

If you have for example 3x10 matrix. It doesn't output.

Input:

```
3 

7

1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Output: should get to 13, but it stops at 8.

Comment: Show an example of what you are trying to get.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't look that bad: [**test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/788da1987b770858). 16 numbers in, 16 numbers out, no duplicate. Can you provide a counter example?

Comment: @Scheff, I just did.

Comment: Well, could reproduce: [**test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b96448bda01ae4b0).

Comment: I suspect, for odd `min(r, c) / 2`, half of the loop body has to be repeated.

Comment: I changed the loop bail-out: [**test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/575a6d6d793dddd5). It's not yet done but better: (20 of 21 numbers printed). ;-)

Comment: Now, it prints all: [**possible fix on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25e381ef8b81a8ea) (not yet tested thouroughly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by carefully fine-tuning the bail-out conditions / ranges of the `for` loops:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // :-(

int main() {
    //freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    //freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int r, c;
    cin >> r >> c;
    int r_beg = 0, r_end = r - 1, c_beg = 0, c_end = c - 1;

    int **m = new int*[r];

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new int[c];
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int runs = min(r, c);;)
    {
        for (int i = c_beg; i <= c_end; i++)
            cout << " " << m[r_beg][i];
        ++r_beg;    
        for (int i = r_beg; i <= r_end; i++)
            cout << " " << m[i][c_end];
        --c_end;
        if (!--runs) break;

        for (int i = c_end; i >= c_beg; i--)
            cout << " " << m[r_end][i];
        --r_end;
        for (int i = r_end; i >= r_beg; i--)
            cout << " " << m[i][c_beg];
        ++c_beg;
        if (!--runs) break;

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        delete[] m[i];
    delete[] m;

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 14 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

[**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/I9tkud)

Input:

```
4 4
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 8 12 16 15 14 13 9 5 6 7 11 10
```

**Notes:**

1. I changed the bail-out of the `for` loop:
   Instead of `min(r, c) / 2`, I use `min(r, c)` and decrement/check `runs` twice in the body.
2. I adjusted the update of `r_beg`, `r_end`, `c_beg`, and `c_end`.

Comment: @What does it mean for those ;; in your loop?

Comment: @Nap `for (int runs = min(r, c);;)` means: a `for` loop with no condition (defaults to `true`), and no post-expression (also called: iteration expression). Instead, I used `if (!--runs) break;` (in two places) to bail out of this loop. In your sample, the post-expression was missing as well. I moved the condition into the loop body because I want to check twice.

Comment: @Nap A for loop requires three statements in its header: initialisation, stop condition and post-processing, so you *always* need two semicolons to separate them; but all of these three statements can be empty, so in extreme case `for(;;)`, which defines an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

The code, as presented, loops towards center until the smaller of the two dimensions is consumed up. However, if that smaller dimension has odd size, then parts of the central row or column respectively haven't been printed out. You can cover that one with some special case handling after your outer loop:

```
for (int runs = std::min(r, c) / 2; runs--;)
{
    // ...
}

if(c < r)
{
    if(c & 1)
    {
        for (int i = r_beg; i <= r_end; i++)
        //                     ^ (!)
        // don't forget to print last element: there's no second loop
        // that would print the corner element a second time now!
            std::cout << m[i][c_end] << " ";
    }
}
else
{
    // handles the square matrix case as well

    if(r & 1)
    {
        for (int i = c_beg; i <= c_end; i++)
            std::cout << m[r_beg][i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually completed a piece of code. I have included it in the question. What is it missing? Thanks

Comment: @Nap Consider the smaller dimensions only. With each iteration, you'll be printing two lines. But if number of lines is odd, then there's one surplus line. That one you need to handle specifically, which the piece of code in my answer does. Having one iteration more in the for loop for odd dimension (`(min(r, c) + 1)/2`) will fail, for square matrices and those with difference of dimensions > 1 you'll be printing one or several elements twice.